# Grails security plugin: Redirecting post and passing its data

Tags: grails, spring-security

On a gsp, I have a submit that goes to a controller action.  In that action, I want to do some processing, then pass the post parameters from the gsp to another POST method.  How can I do this?

Basically, are POST parameters treated specially in the call to redirect?  Because I'm trying to do the following.  I have some custom gsp that I want to use to create a user account.

```
<form action='save' method='POST' id='createForm' class='cssform' autocomplete='off'>
<input type='text' class='text' name='j_username'/>
<input type='password' class='text' name='j_password'/>
<input type='submit' value='Create' />
</form>
```

I have a save action in my controller that I want to create the user on the db, then login.

```
def save = {
// creating user on DB
def config = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig
String postUrl = "${request.contextPath}${config.apf.filterProcesse sUrl}"
redirect(uri: postUrl, params: params)
}
```

The redirect to j_security_check causes a login failure. I'm suspecting that's due to the redirect.

Answer (score 3):

You can use redirect:

```
redirect(action:'xyz', controller:'Abc', params:params)
```

or you can chain actions:

```
chain(action:'abc', controller:'Xyz',model:["myObject":new MyDomain(params)])
```

[Grails - Controllers - Redirects](http://www.grails.org/Controllers+-+Redirects)

Comment: So POST parameters aren't treated specially?

Answer (score 1):

In class RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter 
add this "super.setPostOnly(false);"

public class RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

```
@Override
public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    SecurityRequestHolder.set((HttpServletRequest)request, (HttpServletResponse)response);
    try {
        super.setPostOnly(false);
        super.doFilter(request, response, chain);
```